# Problems to use scala code project in IntelliJ IDEA 15

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I installed IntelliJ IDEA 15 in order to use it for Scala. When I defined the directories for the project I can't add New Scala code, it doesn't appear and the box icon near Scala didn't change its color to blue. As can be seen:

[image]

I defined a JDK in the project structure:

[image]

And the Scala is installed:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make your `scala` directory a `Source` directory, right click on the `scala` directory, then from the `Mark Directory As` sub-menu, select the `Sources Root`:

[image]
*<sup>Sources Root in IDEA</sup>*

I guess you should make your `project` folder as `Sources Root` as well.

---

#### Creating a Scala Project Using Typesafe Activator

In order to create a scala project using activator templates, first download the latest version of activator from [here](https://www.typesafe.com/activator/download). Then, extract the downloaded archive on wherever location you want and go to that location and type `activator ui` on the command line. After a few seconds, activator ui will be started at  `http://localhost:8888`:

[image]
*<sup>Typesafe Activator UI</sup>*

In the Activator UI, select the `Hello Scala` template, then change the destination folder and finally hit the `Create App` button. Activator will clone the project template into your desired location. Then open the IDEA and Select `Import Project` from the welcome screen and select the project folder. From the `Import Project` window check the `Import project from external model` and select `SBT` and hit `Next` and `Finish` after that:

[image]
*<sup>Import Project</sup>*

Then, after downloading required dependencies by `SBT`, you can start coding in scala!

Comment: Thanks Ali, when I stand on the SCALA directory I doesn't let me to add SCALA code, Just JAVA class and more. How can I add SCALA code?

Comment: In my opinion, use typesafe activator and create a scala project. Then import (not open) that project into IDEA

Comment: Thanks can you explain how to use typesafe activator?

Comment: After that, use `activator new` command and select the `minimal-scala` template. It will create a template project that you can **import** in your IDEA.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ali. Please see the following at minute 3:00: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBuX5HtDoT8 It seems he doesn't have to use typesafe ?

Comment: Thanks again Ali. Can you please add to your answer the screen shots of how can I add the minimal-scala template in activator new and how to load the template?